# How to explain tidal tails and dark matter sub-halos in simple terms?

Tags: dark-matter, tidal-forces, gaia, star-cluster, esa

There is the exciting news by ESA  entitled *[Is the nearest star cluster to the Sun being destroyed?](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Gaia/Is_the_nearest_star_cluster_to_the_Sun_being_destroyed)*

> Data from ESA’s Gaia star mapping satellite have revealed tantalising evidence that the nearest star cluster to the Sun is being disrupted by the gravitational influence of a massive but unseen structure in our galaxy.

I heard about **dark-matter sub-halos** and **tidal tails** before, but I am by no means an expert and Wikipedia is not too helpful for my question: **I would like to use [ESA's animation on Hyades tidal tails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn2Qdrz9JDo) to explain the terms "[dark matter halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter_halo)" and "[tidal tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_tail)" in 2 minutes.** Consider that my audience probably heard the term "dark matter" before, but they have to be reminded about it. The term "galaxy" may be used, maybe even "star cluster", but not much more. May you help me, please?

#### References

- Tereza Jerabkova *et al.*: [The 800 pc long tidal tails of the Hyades star cluster](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2021/03/aa39949-20/aa39949-20.html#S25)